# RPi CM4 no USB boot with Ubuntu 22.04.1 for RPi

Tags: boot, live-usb, raspberrypi, bootloader, usb-installation

Hey I've been having trouble USB booting my RPi CM4 with Ubuntu.

I have already made other [posts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/138833/rpi-cm4-not-booting-ubuntu-22-10-from-usb-2-0) on multiple forums (including the [RPi forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2032695#p2032695)), however I've mostly been referred to here.
The following is a clone of the detailed question from the RPi StackExchange:

---

I'm having trouble getting started with my Raspberry Pi 4 Compute Module with 32G eMMC Storage.
It's installed on the RPi Compute Module IO board so USB booting is a little different for it (no USB3) in comparison to the 4B.

I've successfully installed the Ubuntu 22.04 image from the RPi imager app on the embedded storage but I want to not wear it out ahead of actually using it since I want to develop my own PiLFS Distro on it (using the Pi as a dev env) so I flashed the image to the big USB I got kicking around.

Trying to boot the USB with Raspbian x64 (lite) works totally fine:

`Boot loader console, Square color wheel image, short grey screen, boot console, terminal.`

Ubuntu however, gives me a really hard time.
It will read the USB, start booting from it but then turn off all USB power, resulting in a freeze on an Ubuntu grey screen.

(`Boot loader console, Square color wheel image, grey screen, USB power stops`)

Alternatively without `USB_MSD_PWR_OFF_TIME=0`:

`Boot loader console, Square color wheel image, USB power off (~half a second), green LED flicker, USB power on, Boot eMMC)`

My bootloader configuration is as follows:

```
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0

# Boot Order Codes, from https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#BOOT_ORDER
# Try SD first (1), followed by, USB PCIe, NVMe PCIe, USB SoC XHCI then network
#BOOT_ORDER=0xf25641
BOOT_ORDER=0xf165

# Set to 0 to prevent bootloader updates from USB/Network boot
# For remote units EEPROM hardware write protection should be used.
ENABLE_SELF_UPDATE=1

MAX_RESTARTS=5
#HDMI_DELAY=5
#VL805

NET_INSTALL_ENABLED=1
NET_INSTALL_KEYBOARD_WAIT=900
USB_MSD_PWR_OFF_TIME=0
```

(I've already tried with and without USB_MSD_PWR_OFF_TIME=0)

The working config.txt from Raspbian lite is:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
#dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
```

cmdline.txt is:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7c249dcd-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

The default (non-working) Ubuntu config.txt is:

```
[all]
kernel=vmlinuz
cmdline=cmdline.txt
initramfs initrd.img followkernel

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2
arm_boost=1

[all]
# Enable the audio output, I2C and SPI interfaces on the GPIO header. As these
# parameters related to the base device-tree they must appear *before* any
# other dtoverlay= specification
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Comment out the following line if the edges of the desktop appear outside
# the edges of your display
disable_overscan=1

# If you have issues with audio, you may try uncommenting the following line
# which forces the HDMI output into HDMI mode instead of DVI (which doesn't
# support audio output)
#hdmi_drive=2

[cm4]
# Enable the USB2 outputs on the IO board (assuming your CM4 is plugged into
# such a board)
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]

# Enable the KMS ("full" KMS) graphics overlay, leaving GPU memory as the
# default (the kernel is in control of graphics memory with full KMS)
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

# Autoload overlays for any recognized cameras or displays that are attached
# to the CSI/DSI ports. Please note this is for libcamera support, *not* for
# the legacy camera stack
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1

# Config settings specific to arm64
arm_64bit=1
dtoverlay=dwc2
```

(I have already tried using the Raspbian config.txt with ubuntu)
The not-working Ubuntu cmdline.txt is:

```
zswap.enabled=1 zswap.zpool=z3fold zswap.compressor=zstd dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writeable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash
```

What is the correct configuration to USB (MSD) boot the CM4 with Ubuntu 22.04?
Where does the problem seem to lie?

I will appreciate all help given, as this is the third Forum I've asked in!
Thanks in advance!!

---

This is the fifth forum now

Comment: I understand Raspberry Pi's do not boot from USB's. Are you using the ARM64 version of Ubuntu?

Comment: RPis DO boot from USBs and I am using the ARM64 version of Ubuntu. spceifically I'm using the RPi Build of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will give it a try today on my RPi. I am using Ubuntu Mate (ARM 64) myself.

Comment: PS: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot Documentation

Comment: Ah, Yes, now I remember. Converting to USB boot is a one time thing, there is no going back to SD once converted.

Comment: You can change the boot order to fail-over to SD. There IS going back.